# Time data with gmt does not match format input for pandas conversion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, formatting, valueerror

How to convert date time string with GMT into a pandas date time format ?

Here is an example :

```
#date_time is like 12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format="%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S %Z")
```

Here is the error :

> ValueError: time data '12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100' does not match
>   format '%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S %Z' (match)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better check the formatted string:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Use `'%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'` instead of `'%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S %Z'`.

Comment: Thanks, I have no error. But it is super long, do you know a faster way to parse this ?